# Discrepancy between PHP and JS's timestamps

Tags: php, javascript, unix, date, timestamp

This is insane. How should I deal with it?

In Chrome console:

```
new Date(2013,0,1).getTime() // 1st of Jan 2013
> 1356991200000
------------
new Date(2013,0,1).getTime()== 1356991200000
> true
```

Now take that value in PHP:

```
<?php 
    die(date('l, j F Y'), 1356991200000 / 1000); // cut some ms
?>
```

I get `Monday, 31 December 2012`

Is this related to GMT? How do I fix this?

Comment: Psst, [DateTime](http://php.net/class.datetime), [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/class.datetimezone)

Comment: I work with dinosaurs and dragons they can't handle php upgrades

Comment: Which specific version are you limited to?  No DateTimeZone implies you're stuck on 5.1 or 5.0...

Comment: No, I just bluntly added 12 more hours in the comparison functions. They should account for timeshifts like these now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript works with the timezone on the client whereas PHP works with the servers timezone.

**JS**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

```
var x = new Date()
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset()/60
```

**PHP**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Comment: True, but in the question he gives PHP a specific timestamp, so it's not specific to the server time.

Comment: @kojiro But the server formats the time according to the set timezone. Different timezone, different date.

Answer (score 3):

Use either one (I would recommend server side). You can't relay that both will be in sync. One depends of your server and the other depends of the user's computer.

If you need to show something use relative time and update the client side time once the page refresh...